# How do I replace a string with another string?

Tags: c++, replace

I've sat on this problem for quite some time and I can't figure out, what to do.

I am trying to write a programm, that reads a text file, searches and replaces string and saves the file  under a new name. Depending on your input with minimum and maximum value as well as inkrement, several files are created.

Everything works except the replacing of a string (function replaceVariable).

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <conio.h> 
    using namespace std;



    string replaceVariable(string text1, string oldVariable, long double wert){
       cout<< "replace-function open............."<<endl;
       size_t foundAt = text1.find(oldVariable); //find position of old variable
       cout<<"position old variable: "<<foundAt<<endl;

       string newText = to_string(wert); //convert long double 'wert' to string
       cout<<"new variable: "<<newText<<endl;
       size_t lengthNewText = newText.length(); //find length of new string

       string text2= text1.replace(foundAt, lengthNewText, newText); //replace with new string    with length 'lengthNewText' starting at position 'foundAt' 

       return text2;
   }




void writeFile ( string text, string filename ){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ( filename.c_str() );
    myfile << text;
    cout<<"file written.............."<<endl;
    myfile.close();
  }


template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T const& value) {
    stringstream sstr;
    sstr << value;
    return sstr.str();
}



int main(){

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test\\testing.txt");//open the input file

    if (inFile.is_open()){
        cout<< "file open"<<endl<<endl;
        stringstream strStream;
        strStream << inFile.rdbuf();
        string str = strStream.str();

        cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<< str << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl<<endl;
        string line;
        string name;


        long double minWert = 0;
        long double maxWert = 0;
        long double inkWert = 0;



        cout << "Enter minimum value:" << endl;
        cin >> minWert;
        cout << "Enter maximum value:" << endl;
        cin >> maxWert;
        cout << "Enter inkrement:" << endl;
        cin >> inkWert;

        int numFiles = (maxWert-minWert)/inkWert + 1; //calculation number of files needed
        cout << "minimum value: " << minWert << endl;
        cout << "maximum value: " << maxWert << endl;
        cout << "inkrement: " << inkWert << endl;
        cout << "number of files: " << numFiles << endl<<endl<<endl;

        string oldVariable = "xyz     "; //string to be replaced, xyz followed by 5 spaces

        for( int fileNum = 1; fileNum <= numFiles; ++fileNum )  {
            cout<< "loop number: "<< fileNum<<endl; 
            string output = str;

            replaceVariable(output, oldVariable, minWert);

            cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout << output << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl<<endl;

            string text = output;

            name = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test\\comp";
            name += to_string( fileNum );
            name += ".bdf";
            writeFile( text, name );

            cout<<minWert<<endl;

            minWert = minWert+inkWert;

            cout <<"new Minimalwert: "<< minWert<<endl<<endl;
        }
        inFile.close();
    }   else{cout << "Unable to open file";}

 getch();
return 0;
}
```

I've already searched numerous sites and googled every thinkable combination.
Do you have any ideas what might help?

Comment: Did this have any input data and console output? It really belongs in the question so as to demonstrate the problem you're experiencing. Likewise clarity in whether your intent is to replace *all* occurrences or just the first one. In short, define expected behavior and exhibit actual behavior to make this a good question.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the requirements are?  You're doing a textual search, and replacing it with a converted `double`.  If you are trying to replace a floating point value in the textual input, the problem is a lot more complicated, since a single floating point value may have several different representations.

Answer (score 0):

If your functionality of the function **`'replaceVariable'`** is right then this might be the issue,

```
string output = str;
/*function replaceVariable is returning replaced string but you didn't receive
at the calling place and assign back to output(which you are writing in output file)*/
replaceVariable(output, oldVariable, minWert);
```

So replace like,

```
string output = replaceVariable(str, oldVariable, minWert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Several points to be noted in your code.

First, `string::find` may return `npos` if the pattern string is not found, you should check that.

Second, `string::replace` does an **inplace** replacement on the original string, for better performance you could pass the `text1` argument by reference.

Third, `replaceVariable` only replaces the first occurrence of the variable, is that really what you want?

Here is my version of replacing patterns in a string:

```
// replaces at most `limit` occurrences of pattern `p` in text `s` with string `repl`.
// if `limit` <= 0, replace all occurrences.
// returns number of replacement that actually took place.
int replace(std::string &s, const std::string &p, const std::string &repl, int limit=0) {
  int nrepl = 0;
  size_t pos = 0,
         plen = p.length(),
         rlen = repl.length(),
         npos = std::string::npos;

  while ((pos = s.find(p, pos)) != npos) {
    s.replace(pos, plen, repl);
    pos += rlen;
    ++nrepl;
    if (limit > 0 && nrepl >= limit) break;
  }

  return nrepl;
}
```

Hope that helps.